# Is it possible to add native query in hibernate for using as entity select?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

When a class annotated with `@Entity` annotaion hibernate uses queries like `SELECT * FROM class_name`. But for some reason it is needed to run custom select query for class. Is there a way to provide such query?

Comment: yes it is possible , write the query you want to run , in order to help you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, according to the [official hibernate reference](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13696), you can do it like:

```
sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM CATS").addEntity(Cat.class);
```

or:

```
sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT ID, NAME, BIRTHDATE FROM CATS").addEntity(Cat.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Criteria cr = getCurrentSession().createCritiera(class_name.class) 
.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
.add(Projections.property("id"), "id")
.add(Projections.property("name"), "name"))
.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(class_name.class));
List<class_name> list = cr.list();
```

Act as `select id,name from class_name` this will return `List` of `class_name` containing objects only have `id` and `name` and the rest of variables in `class_name`  will be `null` (as you only selected `id` and `name`)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you getHibernatTemplate() from HibernateDaoSupport. Afterwards you can call find("from Class where....") and you get back an object which you can cast to your java class easily.

i.e. 
    List < User >  users = (List < User > )getHibernateTemplate("from User");